# Is there a way to go back and edit the information the user entered?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a simple code written in Python 2.7 that will ask users for certain information, and it exports the information to a .csv file. Once the user inputs the data, is there a way for them to go back and edit what they entered after pressing enter? Here is what i have so far:

```
def writer():
import csv

with open('Work_Order_Log.csv', 'a') as f:
    w=csv. writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    while (1):
        Correct=True
        Employee=True
        WorkOrder=True
        Item=True
        Qty=True
        Process=True
        Date=True
        Time=True
        while Correct:
            Correct=False
            Employee=False
            WorkOrder=False
            Item=False
            Qty=False
            Process=False
            Date=False
            Time=False
            Employee=raw_input("1. Enter Your Name:")
            WorkOrder=raw_input("2. Enter The Work Order Number:")
            PartNumber=raw_input("3. Enter The Item Number:")
            Qty=raw_input("4. Enter Quantity:")
            Process=raw_input("5. Enter Process:")
            Date=raw_input("6. Enter Date(mm/dd):")
            Time=raw_input("7. Total Time(hh:mm):")
            needToCorrect=raw_input("Is the last Entry Correct? (If so, type 'y') If not enter the Number of the Field that is incorrect:")
            if needToCorrect=="1":
                Employee=True
            elif needToCorrect=="2":
                WorkOrder=True
            elif needToCorrect=="3":
                Item=True
            elif needToCorrect=="4":
                Qty=True
            elif needToCorrect=="5":
                Process=True
            elif needToCorrect=="6":
                Date=True
            elif needToCorrect=="7":
                Time=True
            w.writerow([Employee,WorkOrder,Item,Process,Qty,Date,Time,Correct])

writer()
```

After testing the code, I have found that when I enter the number of the incorrect field for correction, it shows in the .csv file that it was incorrect, but still makes me go through the entire loop to fix the errors. Why is this?

Comment: In addition to what the Accepted Answer already says, I would highly recommend getting your data all squared away and _only then_ opening and writing out the file, rather than holding open a filehandle through the entire process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all of your input into a while block:

```
while (1):
    Correct = True
    while Correct:
        Correct = False
        Employee=raw_input("Enter Your Name:")
        ...

        needToCorrect=raw_input("Is the last Entry Correct?(y/n):")
        if needToCorrect == "n": 
             Correct = True
    w.writerow([Employee,WorkOrder,PartNumber,Process,Qty,Date,Time,Correct])
```

Then if a user notices something is incorrect, an "n" will prompt the user to return and retype the fields. If you want only to correct certain fields, a similar, more complicated, method would work fine.

Comment: Two questions: Is there a way to change the data in the .csv file, and  how would i go about making it so that certain fields could be corrected?

Comment: 1. Since the data isn't written to the csv until the user deems it is correct, you don't need to worry about going and changing the data in the .csv file.

Comment: 2. You could have something like `Employee = raw_input("1. Name:")`, thus assigning each item a number. Then when you ask if everything is correct, you can have the user input the item number that needs to be changed, then that would set some variable (like `correct1`) to be true. The `while` block would go `while Correct: if correct1: Employee = raw... if correct2: WorkOrder = raw_...` and so on. You would also need to set each `correct(n)` boolean to true at first, then set them to false. If you want the user to correct multiple lines, then do `if n in Correct: correct(n) = false`.

Comment: bug: `if needToCorrect = "n":` you use assignment instead of equality.  Should be `if needToCorrect == "n":`

Comment: @roippi Thanks! Happens every time... :)

Comment: @user2675961 To simply fix the error, unindent the `writerow` statement by one to pull it out of the inner `while` block. Also, you need to have more `if` statements so that you only go back and edit the ones that were incorrect. Also, you need to use separate variables for the booleans and the strings.